# Account confirmation email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I have a project, and in this project I want to make the SignUp page at the beginning, so I have the following scenario:
When the user presses SignUp , a message is displayed that a message has been sent to his e-mail, a message is sent to his e-mail, and he must go to his e-mail to confirm his e-mail and to confirm his account on my site, but if a message is not sent, he must The user can click on the "Resend Activation Link" button that appears in the picture.
the problem is that there is this api that was created on the back end side for use on the front end side:

```
           router.get('/reactivate/:email', accountController.resendActivationLink);
```

This api is useful when you press "Resend Activation Link" to send a message to the e-mail.
But there is an error on the front side, as the message is not sent, noting that I did not know how to send the api.
This is the "ConfirmEmail" code, meaning this interface that was made through VueJs.
How is this problem solved?
confirmEmail.Vue:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="mt-10">
    <v-layout row class="padding mb-9 ">
      <v-flex xs3 sm5 offset-sm3>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto mt-5 pa-5 text-center secondary"
          max-width="1000"
          max-height="2000px"
          id="limited-products"
          outlined
        >
          <v-btn class="ma-2 mt-10 ml-10 mr-10 icon-size" outlined fab color="blue" large>
            <v-icon large class="icon-size" color="blue darken-2">
              mdi-email
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>

          <v-layout row class="pt-10">
            <v-flex xs12>
              <div class="text-center phase-style">
                Verify Your email address
              </div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>

          <span class="SeparatorRow LoginDefaultView-separatorRow pt-6 ml-15 mr-15"
            ><span class="SeparatorRow-horizontalLine"></span
            ><span class="SeparatorRow-horizontalLine"></span
          ></span>

          <v-layout row class="p-long-style pt-6 ml-15 mr-15">
            <v-flex xs12>
              <div>
                We sent you an email to verify the email. Please check the email
                to activate your account. 
                
                <div class="mt-10 p-size">If you do not receive any message on
                your email, press the button to resend the message again.</div>
              </div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>

          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 class="pt-8 pb-8  ml-15 mr-15">
              <v-btn
                @click="onConfirmEmail"
                class="blue darken-2 color myfont font-weight-bold "
                align="center"
                justify="center"
                block
                large
              >
                Resend Activation Link
              </v-btn>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>

          <span class="SeparatorRow LoginDefaultView-separatorRow pt-6">
            <span class="SeparatorRow-horizontalLine1"></span
          ></span>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import ActionsTypes from "../store/types/actions-types";

export default {
    
    methods:{
         ...mapActions({
      confirmEmail: ActionsTypes.GET_REACTIVATION_EMAIL_ACTION
    }),
        onConfirmEmail(){

      this.confirmEmail()
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("This is the result to Verify Email:" ,res);
            this.$router.push("/signin");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.button {
  background: #b92c28 !important;
  color: aliceblue !important;
  display: flex;
}

.myfont {
  font-family: "Mansalva", cursive;
  color: #e8ecee;
}

.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.padding {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.icon-size {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.phase-style {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.p-long-style{
    font-size: 19px;
}

.p-size{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.SeparatorRow {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.SeparatorRow-horizontalLine {
  border-top: 1px solid #e8ecee;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.SeparatorRow-horizontalLine1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #e8ecee;
  flex: 0.1 0.1 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  min-width: 0.5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.LoginDefaultView-separatorRowLabel {
  color: #cbd4db !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

And this is the Action File.
actions.js:

```
import { email } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import api from "../../../../axiosWithDelimiterFile";
import ActionsTypes from "../types/actions-types"
import MutationsTypes from '../types/mutations-types'
const actions ={
      async [ActionsTypes.GET_REACTIVATION_EMAIL_ACTION](_, userData) {
        console.log('userData: ', userData);
        email = userData.email;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          api
            .post("/account/reactivate/", email)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log("The request is successed")
              resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              reject(error);
            });
        });
      }
}
export default actions;
```

And this file by which api is determined from the backend side, and it is NodeJs.
account.route.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router()
const accountController = require('../controllers/account.controller');
router.get('/reactivate/:email', accountController.resendActivationLink);       
module.exports = router;
```

And this is the function of re-sending the message to the e-mail through the backend, which is NodeJs.
account.controller.js:

```
const userService = require("../services/user.service");
const operationsCodes = require("../utils/operations-codes");

module.exports = {
  resendActivationLink: async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.params.email;
    const response = await userService.resendActivationLink(email);
    return res
    .status(operationsCodes.getResponseCode(response.code))
    .json(response);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Good start on this! It looks like you may be calling your API enpdoint incorrectly, though. The endpoint in question is `'/reactivate/:email'` which implies that you need to use the endpoint like this:

`api.get('/reactivate/user@gmail.com')`

instead of

`api.post("/account/reactivate/", email)`

and your API will process that email address as the `req.params.email`.

Note I'm using a `GET` request, not a `POST` request and just including the email address and part of the endpoint.

Comment: No, it did not help me,
The question is that I have an error in using this api and passing the e-mail in the confirmEmail file,How can i pass email in "ConfirmEmail" File.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. You need to be able to call `this.confirmEmail(this.email)`. That means on your Vue component (`confirmEmail.Vue`) you must have a `data` member called `email`. I'm not sure how you can retrieve that email though. Do you have it in the URL? How do you know which email to send to?